# How to get these buttons float right and vertically aligned with some vertical spacing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Below is my code.

The button with current code are getting displayed at bottom, whereas I want them to be displayed at right most position in vertical manner. Below is my code

```
<div class= "container-fluid">
    <div class = "row">
        <div class = "col-sm-2">
        </div>

        <div class = "col-sm-8">
            <div name="visList">
                <div name="dispTestList">
                    <div class = "panel" >
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div name="col-sm-2"><h4>ABC HEADING</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div name="col-sm-4">
                                    Desc1 : <span>Random Desc</span> | Desc 2 : 
                                    <span>Some Random</span> | Desc3 : <span>Random Desc</span> | Desc 4 : 
                                    <span>Some Random</span>
                                </div>
                                <div name="buttonSection" class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="pull-right">
                                        <a class = "btn btn-success" style="margin-top: 1%;">Take Test</a>
                                        <a class="btn btn-success">View Result</a>
                                        <a class="btn btn-success">View Answers</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div> <!-- Row -->
                        </div> <!-- Panel Body -->
                    </div> <!-- Panel -->

                </div>
            </div> <!-- visible the section -->
        </div> <!-- col-sm-8 -->

        <div class = "col-sm-2">
        </div>

    </div> <!-- Row -->
</div> <!-- container fluid -->
```

The js fiddle is this http://jsfiddle.net/DashmeetSingh/k6EUK/

I want buttons to get displayed like below webpage.

http://www.starsports.com/cricket/tour/tourid=160/schedule/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To align your buttons to the right-hand side, try: `div.pull-right { float: right; }`.  You could also put the buttons in a list if you want them to stack vertically.

```
<div class="pull-right">
    <ul class="buttons">
        <li><a class = "btn btn-success" style="margin-top: 1%;">Take Test</a></li>
        <li><a class="btn btn-success">View Result</a></li>
        <li><a class="btn btn-success">View Answers</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

(To remove the bullet points, you can use the list-style shorthand CSS like this: `ul.buttons { list-style: none }`.)

Comment: The pull-right isnot taking it to extreme right of panel. It is getting stuck in between. I suppose, its soemthing because of margin between panel body and row classes. How to resolve this? Could adding conatiner-fluid would resolve this??

Comment: I've just tried the `div.pull-right { float: right; }` on the fiddle you link to in your question, and unfortunately the buttons are far right aligned for me, which makes it difficult to suggest a fix.Could you maybe provide a little more info about what you're seeing?  It's possible my OS+browser combination is handling this a little differently, or that the fiddle is missing some changes you've made since you asked the question?